# backbone.js change url parameter of a Model and fetch does not update data fetched

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following Model:

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     initialize: function(props){
          this.url = props.url;
     } 

     parse: function(){

          // @override- parsing data fetched from URL
     }


});

 // instantiate
  var mod = new MyModel({url: 'some/url/here'});
```

I use this global variable 'mod' to fetch some data into this model from backend.

```
 // fetch

 mod.fetch({
       success: function(){ ...},
       error: ...

 });
```

All above works well....
My Issue: I want to reuse this model by changing resetting the url and call fetch but it does not update the url somehow. I have tried the following:

```
  mod.fetch({ 
       data: {url:'/some/other/url'},
       postData: true,
       success: function(){ //process data},
       error: ...
  });


 mod.set({url: '/some/other/url'});
 // called fetch() without data: and postData: attributes as mentioned in previous
```

How do I set the url for my model so that I could call fetch() and it fetches data from updated url? Am I missing something. Thanks for any pointers..

**UPDATE 1**: Basically, I am unable to get updated values if I did

```
    model.set({url: 'new value'});
```

followed by

```
    model.fetch();
```

'model' is a global variable. Creating a fresh instance of 'model' works:

```
    model = new Model({url:'/some/other/url'}); 
    model.fetch();
```

however, works as required. Does this mean that a model instance is permanently attached to a url and it cannot be reset?

**ANSWER TO MY QUESTION in UPDATE 1** Model instance is not permanently attached to a url. It can be reset dynamically. Please read through @tkone's thorough explanation and then @fguillens' solution for a better understanding.

Comment: why are you changing the URL? the idea behind a RESTful webservice is that your object is always available at the same URL (with an ID as necessary for a specific object)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After have understood the @tkone 's explanation...

If you still want to have a dynamic `Model.url` you always can delay its construction to *run time*, try this:

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function(){
    return this.instanceUrl;
  },
  initialize: function(props){
    this.instanceUrl = props.url;
  } 
}
```

Comment: You can do: `mm = new MyModel; mm.url = '/mynewurl/';` as well.  Backbone is super flexible with this stuff.

Comment: @fguillen - Thanks!! this delaying the construction to run time did the trick!!

Answer (score 11):

Well the answer here is that you want to do:

```
mod.url = '/some/other/url'
```

The URL isn't part of the instance of the model itself, but rather an attribute of the `MyModel` object that you're creating your model instance from.  Therefore, you'd just set it like it was an normal JavaScript object property.  `set` is used only when the data you're setting (or conversely getting with `get`) is actually an attribute of the data you want to send/receive from the server.

But why you're changing the URL is the question we should be asking. The idea behind Backbone's model/collection system is that you speak to a REST endpoint and each model has a corresponding endpoint.

Like you've got a blog and that blog has an "entry" object which is available at:

```
/rest/entry/
```

And you've got a Backbone model for Entry:

```
Entry = Backbone.Model.extend({urlBase: '/rest/entry'});
```

Now when you `save` or `fetch` Backbone knows how this works.

So like you're making a new model:

```
e = new Entry();
e.set({title: "my blog rulez", body: "this is the best blog evar!!!!1!!"});
e.save();
```

This would then make Backbone do an HTTP POST request to `/rest/entry` with the body:

```
{
  "title": "my blog rulez",
  "body": "this is the best blog evar!!!!1!!"
}
```

(When you do your `mod.set({url: '/some/other/url'});` you're actually adding a field called `url` to the dataset, so the server would send `"url": "/some/other/url"` as part of that JSON POST body above:

```
{
  "title": "my blog rulez",
  "body": "this is the best blog evar!!!!1!!",
  "url": "/some/other/url" 
}
```

The server would then respond with an HTTP 200 (or 201) response with the same model, only with, like, say, and ID attached:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "my blog rulez",
  "body": "this is the best blog evar!!!!1!!"
}
```

And that's not what you're looking for, right?)

Now you've got this model and it's got an ID.  This means if you change it:

```
e.set('title', 'my blog is actually just ok');
e.save()
```

Backbone now makes an HTTP PUT request on `/rest/entry/1` to update the resource on the server.

The server sees that you're talking about ID 1 on the `/rest/entry/` endpoint, so knows to update an existing record (and send back an HTTP 200).

TL;DR

Don't change the URL, Backbone will. Make a new model for a new piece of data.

Comment: thanks for ur explanation! I have a model and url param assoc with that. when I initialize this model I pass a url value and call fetch().Now I want to change this 'url' value as the data fetched into this model will still have same params: for example url1: /top ; url2: /top/filter1 ; url3: /top/filter2 .I am not sure if it is good practice but all 3 urls will return same data from the backend except there will be filtering as specified. I require to switch between urls based on the 'tabs' clicked. I can have multiple Models as you mentioned but I was thinking if I could reuse.

Comment: @Vikram so you're trying to only get back a limited set of data filtered by your filter parameter?  I would recommend making a new collection for each set of data, and changing the `url` attribute of the collection.  So you'd have a collection called `filter1` who's URL attribute is set to `/top/filter1`, and so forth.

Comment: yes precisely! it returns the same type of data just that some rows maybe filtered depending upon filter applied...which is why I was considering reusing as I do not have to keep track (I am also persisting the models locally) of many different models which would contain similar data....

Comment: @Vikram If the data is all the same (as in it's all the same model), I'd handle this at the collection level, which is exactly what backbone's collections are designed to do.  It's a bunch of instances of the same model in a grouping that lets you sort, iterate, etc.

Comment: thanks for your feedback...I still have one question and it may sound repetitive but do you think this scenario is even possible(may be a bad practice but still asking): var model = new Model({url:'/some/url'}); model.fetch({success: function(){//do something with data}}); model.set(url, '/some/other/url') //NOTE: I am not doing save()....just set()... model.fetch() fetches some other data? ... let say all 3 urls I mentioned in comment above return just 1 row (SQL Query with LIMIT 1 Clause) but different row based on filter...then I think a Model would suffice instead of Collection

Comment: if you're getting back just one object, then yeah, you can use the model -- but you could still use a collection.  either way will work.

Answer (score 4):

```
model.urlRoot = "/your/url"
```

OR

```
model.urlRoot = function(){ return "/your/url"; }
```

OR

```
model.url = "/your/url"
```

OR

```
model.url = function(){ return "/your/url"; }
```

Default 'url' property of a Backbone.Model object is as below. Backbone.js doc says:

> Default URL for the model's representation on the server -- if you're using Backbone's restful methods, override this to change the endpoint that will be called.

```
url: function() {
  var base = getValue(this, 'urlRoot') || getValue(this.collection, 'url') || urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  return base + (base.charAt(base.length - 1) == '/' ? '' : '/') + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
},
```

Clearly, It first gets the value of urlRoot, if not available, it will look at the url of the collection to which model  belongs. By defining urlRoot instead of url has an advantage of falling back to collection url in case urlRoot is null.

Comment: thank you for taking your time to answer! I was looking at a way to switch the url in a model dynamically based upon the url that my application generates. The answer I checked works very well for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can set url as option in fetch function, like this:

```
var mod = new MyModel();
mod.fetch({
   url: '/some/other/url',
   data: {}
});
```