# Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified for a CollectionView

Tags: backbone.js

I know this error has come up a few times, but I'm still not sure how to make this work appropriately..

My magic begins here :

```
    var list_edit_member_view = new app.views.ListMemberEdit({
      el: $("#enterprise_member_list_edit_container"),
      list_ids: list_ids
    });
    list_edit_member_view.render();
```

And this loads this View (**ListMemberEdit.js**) which has this in the render() :

```
this.list_edit_member_view = new app.views.CollectionView({
  el: $("#enterprise_member_list_edit_container"),
  collection: app.peers,
  list_item: app.views.ListMemberEditSelection, 
  list_item_options: {list_ids: this.options.list_ids} 
});
```

Which loads a CollectionView view that renders its `list_item_options` as model views.. It is within this file (`ListMemberEditSelection.js`), that when I perform `this.destroy`, it will return :

```
Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

So this makes me think that the Model or the Model URL is not being defined.. I'm just not sure where to put this since it works very similar to my other partials that are doing roughly the same thing..

Any thoughts? My apologies for the vagueness. Let me know if there's anything else you would like to look at!

I'm curious if its possible to see *where* this URL attribute would be written within the Object Model or Collection itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because `destroy()` function will call `Backbone.sync` to update the server too, not only your models in the frontend. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy

So, if you're using REST to sync your data, you'll need to set a url property in your model so Backbone know where to send request:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "http://myapi.com/"
})
```

To allow more flexibility, you can also set a urlRoot: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

Comment: Hmmm.. It seems to be working elsewhere without this `url` instantiated in the Model like you describe. In the working aspect, if I do `$.bar.model.collection.url`, I can find a URL written out.. so the question is.. where is that collection URL instantiated if its not done within the model like you suggest..

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, I removed the `"id":""` from my models default values and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I did receive similar error
Try this: I am just making an assumption what your model might look like

```
window.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function(){
    return this.instanceUrl;
  },
  initialize: function(props){
    this.instanceUrl = props.url;
  } 
}
```

Please look at this question that I had posted myself for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700275/405117

I am providing this reference as the answers here helped me better understand

Hope this helps!